# Navigation View headerLayout redundant issues

Tags: android, header, android-navigationview

My navigation drawer have redundant header view . Anyone facing this issues ?

My code for my header view :

```
private FrameLayout flHeaderContainer;
private NavigationView drawer;
drawer = (NavigationView) drawerLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer);
flHeaderContainer = (FrameLayout) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.drawer_header,null);
drawer.addHeaderView(flHeaderContainer);
flHeaderContainer.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Another issues is , my first "sign in" header jave no respond/not clickable , only the second "sign in" header is clickable. Not sure is it a bug or code problem.

I am using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' and
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'

[image]

Comment: add xml layout in question

Comment: In your **XML** you have `app:headerView="drawer_header"`. Remove that.